# How can I combine text in multiple rows into one text block in numbers?

Tags: numbers

I am attempting to automate a set of instructions that have variables. I can combine the text across the rows. But I need to then combine each of the final rows together for one simple text block that I can copy and paste into an email.

For example, the screen shot shows Name, Gallery Link which then combines together in Column C.

How can I create a cell that then collects together all of the rows in Column C?

[image: Numbers, collect all of the Column C rows?]

I want it to look like this at the end.

Bob Bob Gallery Link: http://www.mckeephotography.com/gallery1

Doug Doug Gallery Link: http://www.mckeephotography.com/gallery2

Sue Sue Gallery Link: http://www.mckeephotography.com/gallery3

Sort of a sum of Column C but with text.

Comment: I can't see your images because all 3 links generate the message "Um… We may have moved that one."  with no additional link.

Comment: Well that is unexpected behavior. I can see it on my firefox browser and click the link. But, let me try to simplify my request: If you have a bunch of rows in one column, with text strings (or formulas that generate the text strings) in them, how can you create a footer cell at the bottom that contains all of the text strings?

Comment: I tried your links again with Firefox and Google.  No luck.  But i posted an answer that maybe what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the try. Not sure why the image isn't showing up. However, you solved for a different challenge. That goes across one row and puts together the strings for the row. I am looking to combine all of the text strings in a column. So, combine Row 2-4, column C into one footer cell. Go down instead of across. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CONCATENATE fuction to combine multiple text strings into one. See the image below for an example:

[image].

The next image shows the result.

[image]

Comment: Same problem: Solved for the wrong direction. I need to put together all of column C strings into one cell, prob a footer.

Comment: just switch rows and columns!

Comment: Okay, that gets me closer. However, I think I have to manually add each row to the footer formula. What happens if we add more rows? do I have to add more to the footer cell formula? Right now, I am putting in CONCATENATE(B1, B2, B3, etc) But I would like to not have to adjust any time I add or delete more rows. (I know, I want the world!)